# php array difference

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to find the difference in 2 arrays.

```
$inven_old = array(1,2,3,4); 
$inven_new = array(1,2,3,4,5); 
$result = array_diff($inven_old, $inven_new); 
print_r($result);
```

Why is the outcome nothing?

Shouldn't it be "5" ?

If not, how can I do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: try `var_dump($result)` to see it's structure

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php `Returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.`

Comment: is there a command to do what I need then?

Comment: You can't; array_diff returns all the unique items in the arrays. In both your arrays, 5 and 4 are present, thus nothing in unique. array_diff does not care about the quantity of the elements in the array.

Comment: @user1022585: nope, there is no any built-in one

Comment: @user1022585 more hard PHP code do the job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

`array_diff()` gives the result of subtracting all arrays except the first, from the first. Thus, things which are in the second array but not the first won't show up. (In other words, it's not the *symmetric* difference.)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

> Returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

So if you do:

```
$result = array_diff($inven_new, $inven_old);
```

The result will contain "5".

**Bonus:** If you need something that works regardless of the order of the arrays, try:

```
$result = array_diff($a + $b, array_intersect($a, $b));
```

Answer (score 1):

A very late response but maybe this will help someone sometime ..

```
function array_deep_diff($d1, $d2) {
    if (is_array($d1) && is_array($d2))  {
        $diff = array();
        foreach (array_unique(array_merge(array_keys($d1), array_keys($d2))) as $key) {
            if (!array_key_exists($key, $d1)) {
                $diff['added'][$key] = $d2[$key];
            } else if (!array_key_exists($key, $d2)) {
                $diff['removed'][$key] = $d1[$key];
            } else {
                $tmp = array_deep_diff($d1[$key], $d2[$key]);
                if (!empty($tmp)) $diff[$key] = $tmp;
            }
        }
        return $diff;

    } else if (!is_array($d1) && !is_array($d2))  {
        if ($d1 == $d2) return array();
        $ret = "$d1 ---> $d2";
        // just a little touch for numerics, might not be needed
        if (is_numeric($d1) && is_numeric($d2)) {
            if ($d1 > $d2) $ret .= ' [- ' . ($d1 - $d2) . ']';
            if ($d1 < $d2) $ret .= ' [+ ' . ($d2 - $d1) . ']';
        }
        return $ret;

    } else {
        return array('Array compared with NonArray');
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second array should come first

```
$inven_old = array(1,2,3,4); 
$inven_new = array(1,2,3,4,5); 
$result = array_diff($inven_new, $inven_old); 
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

to make it work as you expect you need to reverse arguments:

```
$result = array_diff($inven_new, $inven_old);
```

Otherwise you are checking which elements are missing in the inven_new, and obsiously none is missing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function but you can easily write a custom one (http://ideone.com/UNRKV):

```
$old = array(5,5,4); 
$new = array(5,5,4,4); 

function array_subtract($a, $b)
{
    foreach ($b as $val) {
        $i = array_search($val, $a);
        if ($i !== false) {
            unset($a[$i]);
        }
    }

    return array_values($a);
}

$result = array_subtract($new, $old);

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This consumes from the first array (`$old`) until all are gone:

```
$result = array();
$old = array_count_values($old);
foreach($new as $value)
{
    @$old[$value] ? $old[$value]-- : $result[] = $value;
}
```

Result:

```
$old = array(5,5,4);
$new = array(5,5,4,4);

...

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  int(4)
}
```