# PHP subtract one list from other

Tags: php, python

In python I have two list with non-unique values:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,5]

b = [1,2,2,2,5,5]
```

To substract b from a
I found solution:

```
from collections import Counter as mset

subtract = mset(a) - mset(b)

list(subtract.elements())

#result is [1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]!!!!!!!!
```

How to do the same in PHP? PHP does not support lists.

**array_diff is not useful, because it deletes non-unique values**

Comment: Not sure there is a bult-in function for this, one approach would be to filter the array (see my answer).

Comment: I answered you, the output is different. Maybe I need to dive into php collections and find solution there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "functional" solution:

```
$a = [1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,5];
$b = [1,2,2,2,5,5];
$bCopy = $b;
$c = array_filter($a, function($item) use(&$bCopy) {
    $idx = array_search($item, $bCopy);
    // remove it from $b if found
    if($idx !== false) unset($bCopy[$idx]);
    // keep the item if not found
    return $idx === false;
});
sort($c);
print_r($c);
```

You will need to make a copy of `$b` as the `array_filter` callback is destructive in regards to the array `$b`. Also you will need to sort the result if you want to have exact the same output as in python.

Comment: output is different 


(
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [6] => 4
    [7] => 3
    [11] => 3
    [12] => 4
)

Comment: I think intuitively it can be solved with new features of last php version or php collections. Unfortunately, I'm not programmer but entrepreneur.

Comment: Thanks with answer. It helped me with my problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29863096/recreate-current-business-state-from-audit-logs

Comment: It helped me to regenerate staff list based on staff in_out movements.

Answer (score 1):

Related answers:

- [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077840/difference-between-two-arrays)
- [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968712/php-array-difference)

For the example you provided, you can try the following:

```
$a = [1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,5];
var_dump($a);
$b = [1,2,2,2,5,5];
var_dump($b);
$c = array_diff($a, $b);
var_dump($c);
```

It should give you the following result:

```
array (size=14)
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 2
  2 => int 3
  3 => int 4
  4 => int 5
  5 => int 5
  6 => int 4
  7 => int 3
  8 => int 2
  9 => int 1
  10 => int 2
  11 => int 3
  12 => int 4
  13 => int 5
array (size=6)
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 2
  2 => int 2
  3 => int 2
  4 => int 5
  5 => int 5
array (size=6)
  2 => int 3
  3 => int 4
  6 => int 4
  7 => int 3
  11 => int 3
  12 => int 4
```

**Update**

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973365/keep-duplicates-while-using-array-diff).

I wrapped the solution in a useful function:

```
function array_diff_duplicates($array1, $array2) {
    $counts = array_count_values($array2);
    $result = array_filter($array1, function($o) use (&$counts) {
        return empty($counts[$o]) || !$counts[$o]--;
    });
    sort($result, SORT_NUMERIC);
    return $result;
}
```

Trying the following:

```
$a = [1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,5];
$b = [1,2,2,2,5,5];
$c = array_diff_duplicates($a, $b);
var_dump($c);
```

Gives the expected result:

```
array (size=8)
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 3
  2 => int 3
  3 => int 3
  4 => int 4
  5 => int 4
  6 => int 4
  7 => int 5
```

Comment: No. Output is different. I need $result = arrray(1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5);